# Constructing drag like model

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuitikz

I am trying something rather new. Though it might take time, I will be glad if anybody could help. I tried to modify the existing figure but they couldn't create what I want.

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[M1/.style={rectangle,draw=black,minimum size=2cm,thick}]
    \tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=5}]
    \tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm]
    \node [M1] (M1) {};
    \node (wall1) [ground, minimum width=3.5cm,yshift=-3cm] {};
    \draw [spring] (wall1.170) -- ($(M1.south east)!(wall1.170)!(M1.south west)$) node[pos=.5,left] {$k_1$};
      \draw [spring] (wall1.25) -- ($(M1.south west)!(wall1.25)!(M1.south east)$) node[pos=.5,right] {$k_2$};
     \node at (0,-3.5) {(a)};
       \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Do you want to know how to draw the figure you posted?  Try to put together a MWE to show us what you were able to come up with and I'm sure someone will guide you in the right direction.  But without further clarification you're not liable to get much help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you've got so far. I'm not currently clear whether the image is the figure you tried to modify or the figure you tried to produce.

Comment: Yes A. Ellett I want to create exactly that using Latex.

Comment: I did what I have shown using visio. But when I saw the similar one executed using latex, I was impressed. I believe if I can just do this, then with my fundamental knowledge in Latex, i can modify it to suit my need subsequently.

Comment: @IsmailLadeleLadipo Honestly your code has nothing to do with your picture at all

Comment: @JouleV I think he improved over the interveening 1001 nights, see his later questions :-)

Comment: @JouleV This is an old question. I edited it while I was searching for something to answer among old questions...

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oops!

Comment: @JouleV It's very good you answered, so the question goes out of the non-answered list!

Comment: @CarLaTeX It is that I thought you were not going to answer, so I answered. I got a notification as soon as I click the post button

Comment: @JouleV I was not going to answer, and even if I was, you are always free to answer before me! And also after, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't hope to get any responses from you, as the question is so old, but this is a proposal from a `circuitikz` newcomer:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (-3,0) rectangle (3,2.5) node[midway] {$M$};
\draw (-2,0) to[R=$k_b$] (-2,-6);
\draw (1,0) to[R=$k_1$] (1,-2);
\draw (1,-2) -- (2,-2) to[R=$k_2$] (2,-5) -| (1,-6);
\draw (1,-5) -- (0,-5) to[damper=$\eta$] (0,-2) -- (1,-2);
\draw (-3.5,-6) rectangle (3.5,-6.5);
\draw[-latex] (3,1.25) -- ++ (2.5,0) -- ++ (0,2) node[above] {$x_2$};
\draw[-latex] (3.5,-6.25) -- ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,2) node[above] {$x_1$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]